# state.resolve returns an empty object in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state defined like so

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    controller: 'LoginController',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.tpl.html',
    data: {
      loginState: true
    },
    resolve: {
      saml_auth: function ($cookies) {
        var saml_auth = $cookies.get('saml_auth');
        console.log(saml_auth) // returns the string value
        return {claim: saml_auth};
      }
    }
```

In the controller, I get an empty object, no properties even within the object

```
angular.module('swSelfService')
  .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = [
  '$scope', 
  'SWSessionService', 
  '$state', 
  '$stateParams', 
  'saml_auth',
];

function LoginController($scope, SWSessionService, $state, saml_auth) {
    console.log(saml_auth) // {}
}
```

Comment: You're missing an argument in your controller constructor (look at the $inject array and the constructor signature).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to add 4th parameter of `$stateParams` injectable on. You placed `saml_auth` at wrong place inside controller constructor, it should appear on 5th place.

```
LoginController.$inject = [
  '$scope', 
  'SWSessionService', 
  '$state', 
  '$stateParams', 
  'saml_auth',
];

function LoginController($scope, SWSessionService, $state, $stateParams, saml_auth) {
    console.log(saml_auth) // {}
}
```